# Google credentials and redirect URI for Google OAuth2 in a WordPress plugin, questions

Tags: plugin-development, api, google, oauth

I'm developing a plugin that inserts contacts into a custom table of the WordPress database (name, phone number, email). It is possible to enter data in this table either manually, through a form, or by importing it from WordPress users. I have also developed a feature to import contacts from Google Contacts (Google People). Everything works but I ask you: when I will provide the plugin to my customers how can I do to avoid also providing the `client_secret.json` file with my credentials for accessing the Google API via OAuth2 together with the plugin?
Furthermore, in order to function correctly, I must also authorize the URI redirect in the Google console but I cannot know in advance the URL of the various sites where the plugin will be installed, is it possible to automate (perhaps always through the Google API) this insertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions depending on what kind of relationship you expect to have with the people that use the plugin.

1. Instruct them how to create an app and which URLs to use to be compatibe with what you expect in the plugin, have a setting page at the wordpress admin in which they can either upload the secrets file or configure the app secrets.
   This option is easy for you hard for the user.
2. Setup a proxy. Your plugin actually comunicates with the proxy and the proxy does the relevant API access, handles oauth redirects from google etc.
   This options is easy for the user but complicates your development, might cost you if you don't have a place to host such a thing, but the biggest thing is the quota limits of google as you will be responsible to pay when you pass the free tier, or your code will need to keep track of the usage and stop before you pass the free tier.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I can't use a proxy, so I might only consider the first solution.
Should I "instruct" the end users of the plugin to create an app in Google Cloud Platform, generate the credentials and then provide a form for entering the credentials or uploading the json file?
It is really impractical for the end user as a solution, 90% may not have the necessary technical skills... This is the first time I try to do something like this with the Google API, I didn't think it was not possible to get a more practical solution.

Comment: I agree it is impractical for all non technical users and even technical ones might find it hard to navigate all the required google settings. OTOH if the feature is important enough for a user they might be willing to pay someone (you?) to configure it for them. It seems like the redirect URL is the biggest hurdle but it is probably required to identify the web app and the same problems happen when you try oauth against facebook and twitter.